# why does using the mvg-api return a json decode error when used

Tags: python

I am working on a program which relies on train data returned from the mvg API about the Munich uBahns. However when I even try to call the API I am immediately met with a `JSONDecodeError`. Is there any way to solve this problem or a different API I could use?

```
import mvg_api
id=mvg_api.get_id_for_station("Hauptbahnhof")
print(id)
```

This is a simple code I tried which should return the station id for Hauptbanhof however it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/"name"/PycharmProjects/MVG/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/"name"/PycharmProjects/MVG/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    id=mvg_api.get_id_for_station("Hauptbahnhof")
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/MVG/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mvg_api/__init__.py", line 148, in get_id_for_station
    station = get_stations(station_name)[0]
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/MVG/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mvg_api/__init__.py", line 202, in get_stations
    results = get_locations(station)
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/MVG/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mvg_api/__init__.py", line 194, in get_locations
    results = _perform_api_request(url)
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/MVG/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mvg_api/__init__.py", line 67, in _perform_api_request
    return resp.json()
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/MVG/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: This error is nearly always from jsonlines format and not json

Comment: Sorry, to clarify that. The error comes from putting JSONLines through a standard JSON parser. The location of the explody part is tell-tale - `line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. That's the usual place where you would expect a JSON parser to hit problems if it's JSONLines. Still, I'm only 90% sure that's what you're trying to parse

Answer (score 1):

The library you are using is using an API that is not supported anymore. From its [github page](https://github.com/leftshift/python_mvg_api):

> Unfortunately, the API endpoint used by this library is no longer available (more details in [#31](https://github.com/leftshift/python_mvg_api/issues/31)).

When you dig through the library's code, you'll see that it tries to get data from e.g., https://www.mvg.de/api/fahrinfo/location/queryWeb?q=Hauptbahnhof and that returns a HTML 404 error page. The library tries to parse that HTML as JSON and (of course) the JSON parser chokes on that.

The [MVV website](https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/fahrplanauskunft/fuer-entwickler/index.html) says an API based on their TIRAS interface is still in development (as of Aug 2023), so you may have to wait for them to eventually publish an API, or you can try an alternative library like [Mondbaron](https://github.com/mondbaron/mvg), as suggested by the mvg-api author, but this may or may not work, and MVV may or may not decide to keep supporting it.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this error you should ensure that your json string is properly formatted and follows the json syntax rules, use online json validators or json lint tools to check the validity of your json string

Comment: This is no better than the error itself. The error already told them it wasn't valid JSON.

Comment: The OP does not control the JSON that the API returns, so this is a pointless comment.